# How to delay jquery step function response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-steps

I m using [**jQuery-step**](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) library with a form combining the [**formvalidation.js**](http://formvalidation.io/examples/jquery-steps/) . i want to delay below method response until ajax complete.

> i want to send return **true/false** when ajax complete.

```
onStepChanging: function (e, currentIndex, newIndex) {

    var fv = $stepForm.data('formValidation'), // FormValidation instance
        // The current step container
        $container = $stepForm.find('section[data-step="' + currentIndex + '"]');

    // Validate the container
    fv.validateContainer($container);
    var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
    if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
        // Do not jump to the next step
        return false;
    }
    if (isValidStep === true) {
        //call ajax here
        //wait for ajax to complete then move to next or keep 
    }
    return true; //-> i want to delay this 

},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: its irrelevant to my question @JoshulSharma

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to return true/false on ajax complete or success callback?

Comment: yeah @funcoding

Comment: As @funcoding is suggesting if you need to just pass true/false after ajax complete, then you can return true/false values on ajax "success" method.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have done by setting property in javascript `window` then wrap the return in setTimeout function

**Step 1:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ window.flag = ''; });
```

**Step 2**

```
function submitForm($stepForm) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://' + location.host + "/ajax",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {'method': 'submitApplication', 'formdata': $stepForm.serialize()},
        success: function (data) {
          window.flag = true;
        }
}
```

**Step 3:**

```
onStepChanging: function (e, currentIndex, newIndex) {
  if (isValidStep === true) {
                submitForm($stepForm);
  }
 .... code
  setTimeout(function () {
     return window.flag;
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Why you need the setTimeout ? Just make the submitForm function a promise an do something on the callback function!

Comment: @Noman , Ajax are async calls, u can never tell if your ajax call will always complete in 2 seconds delay that you have set. Also as per your code you dont deed that 2 second of time out....just set  if (isValidStep === true) {
              return  submitForm($stepForm); and return true/false in "submitForm" function.
  }

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
function submitForm($stepForm) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://' + location.host + "/ajax",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {'method': 'submitApplication', 'formdata': $stepForm.serialize()},
        /* Resolving true on success, you could also return a json object if you need the response */ 
        success: () => { resolve(true); },
        /* Rejecting the promise in case of an error */
        error: () => { reject(false) } 
     })
  })
}
```

Then:

```
onStepChanging: function (e, currentIndex, newIndex) {
  if (isValidStep === true) {
       submitForm($stepForm)
       .then( /*...Do whatever you want ..*/)
       .catch( console.log );
  }
```